# How to distinguish distances between two curves

Tags: statistics

Given the reference line (orange), how do I distinguish between the three cases as shown here?

The coordinates are given for each of the blue and the orange lines. Further, the matching coordinate pairs are also known. So essentially we know the length of the vertical black lines. The average of the distances is the same for all the cases.

[image: orange line: reference, blue line: sample, matching coordinates are given]

I wanted to differentiate the three behaviors as represented in the above. For example, in the first case (a), the blue line is a proper representation of the orange line in terms of shape with a slight shift. This is different from the second and third cases.

It will be good to differentiate between the second and third cases as well. In the second case, the shape gradually deviates from the reference, whereas in the third case (c) there is a sudden bump, but the rest of the shape is in alignment with the reference.

Comment: What exactly do you want to differentiate?

Comment: I added a description to the post. So basically given a set of curves, I wanted to check which ones are aligned to the referenced shape and which ones are not. Further, the ones that do not comply, is there a sudden distortion to otherwise good alignment or is it the case that there is no relationship with the reference shape.

Comment: Are you given the equations of the curves?

Comment: To analogize from probability, you can take the moments of the distances.  You say that the average distance is the same--this is the first moment.  The same will not be true of the averages of the squares of the distances--the "second moment," and so on.  So these higher moments can differentiate between these.

Comment: You are probably looking for the [autocorrelation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation) function

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations. I will try both the higher moments and the autocorrelation function.